# how to indent multiline message printed by python logger?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

Current behaviour:

```
DEBUG:package:123 > message with
multiple lines
foo bar
```

Wanted behaviour:

```
DEBUG:package:123 > message with
                    multiple lines
                    foo bar
```

`DEBUG:package:123` can have different width so it's not possible to adjust message before sending it to logger.

Comment: how are you logging these lines? are you logging them as 3 seperate lines?

Comment: It seems like the easiest thing to do would be to start the message with a `\r\n` so all the desired aligned elements are left-aligned.  Not exactly the requested functionality, but maybe accomplishes the goal very simply.

Answer (score 8):

Existing answers answered the indentation part well. But the new `format` implementation did not handle other fields (e.g. `exec_info`, `stack_info`) properly compared to the original `logging.Formatter`.

The below implementation is based on [simonzack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66638269/10340019) and reuses the original formatter to minimize the side effects.

[edit 2021-11] it also handles formatted values correctly by post-processing the formatted message instead of pre-processing it

```py
class MultiLineFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """Multi-line formatter."""
    def get_header_length(self, record):
        """Get the header length of a given record."""
        return len(super().format(logging.LogRecord(
            name=record.name,
            level=record.levelno,
            pathname=record.pathname,
            lineno=record.lineno,
            msg='', args=(), exc_info=None
        )))

    def format(self, record):
        """Format a record with added indentation."""
        indent = ' ' * self.get_header_length(record)
        head, *trailing = super().format(record).splitlines(True)
        return head + ''.join(indent + line for line in trailing)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's is aiven's version which is more modernized and flexible.

```py
class MultiLineFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        message = record.msg
        record.msg = ''
        header = super().format(record)
        msg = textwrap.indent(message, ' ' * len(header)).lstrip()
        record.msg = message
        return header + msg
```

In order to use this:

```py
formatter = MultiLineFormatter(
    fmt='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
)
log_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```

Answer (score 2):

End up with custom formatter without message in fmt string:

```py
import textwrap

class Formatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Formatter, self).__init__(fmt="%(levelname)-8s %(name)20s:%(lineno)-3d > ")

    def format(self, record):
        header = super(Formatter, self).format(record)
        msg = textwrap.indent(record.message, ' ' * len(header)).strip()
        return header + msg
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified aiven's version to work properly.

```
class Formatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, format_str):
        super(Formatter, self).__init__(fmt=format_str)

    def format(self, record):
        message = record.msg
        record.msg = ''
        header = super(Formatter, self).format(record)
        msg = textwrap.indent(message, ' ' * len(header)).strip()
        record.msg = message
        return header + msg
```